# Not able to validate token when using pre-packaged wso2 identity server as key manager for wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 and configured Pre packaged Identity Server 5.7.0 as Key Manager. When I create an Application in API Store and generate keys I can see that Service Providers are getting created in Identity Server. Also I am able to obtain token using the generated consumer id and secret.
However when I pass that token to my APIs I am getting unclassified authentication error. Below is the exception that I can see in the logs,

**ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.WSAPIKeyDataStore.getAllURITemplates(WSAPIKeyDataStore.java:77)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidator.java:791)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.doGetAPIInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:639)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.findMatchingVerb(APIKeyValidator.java:573)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getResourceAuthenticationScheme(APIKeyValidator.java:357)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.WSAPIKeyDataStore.getAllURITemplates(WSAPIKeyDataStore.java:75)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:183)
        ... 22 more**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check logs in the identity server side. You may able to get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check with this issue [1]

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/3768